# SQL Join did not work (zero records return)?

Tags: sql

I found this question from a tutorial,

```
Emp( eid: integer, ename: string, age: integer, salary: real)
Works( eid: integer, did: string, pct-time: integer)
Dept( did: string, budget: real, managerid: integer)
```

As that question Employee can work many departments. Work table used to map employees and departments. The pct_time field of the Works relation shows the percentage of time that a given employee works in a given department.

**Then it ask to print names and ages of each employee who works in both the Hardware and Software department.**

For that I have written following SQL but it did not work? can someone please explain the issue.

```
SELECT Emp.ename, Emp.age
FROM Emp
JOIN Works ON Works.eid = Emp.eid
WHERE Works.did = 'Hardware' AND Works.did = 'Software'
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please do not use the words 'did not work'. Please explain what you expected and what actually happened (i.e. no records were returned)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the advice, I have updated the question topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single record the `Works.did` can't be Hardware and Software at once. So you need to group your data, filter on the `Works.did` you look for and then take only the groups having **both** `Works.did`

```
SELECT Emp.ename, Emp.age
FROM Emp
JOIN Works ON Works.eid = Emp.eid
WHERE Works.did IN ('Hardware', 'Software')
GROUP BY Emp.ename, Emp.age
HAVING count(Works.did) = 2
```

Comment: No need for count distinct, i.e. `HAVING count(distinct Works.did) = 2`?

Comment: I doubt an employee can be 2 times in the software department

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully help :

```
SELECT Emp.ename, Emp.age
FROM Emp
INNER JOIN Works AS W1 ON W1.eid = Emp.eid
INNER JOIN Works AS W2 ON W2.eid = Emp.eid
WHERE W1.did = 'Hardware' 
AND W2.did = 'Software'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Emp.ename, Emp.age
FROM Emp
JOIN Works ON Works.eid = Emp.eid
WHERE Works.did IN ('Hardware', 'Software')
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING count(distinct Works.did) = 2
```

Comment: Not working, This is the error message "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: 1,2 will work only in MySQL. if you are using sqlserver, replace 1,2 with Emp.ename, Emp.age